# Why when i convert my MRI images to L they dont turn gray?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

I have mri  images when I checked the mode it show that they are RGB but they look like grayscale images so when I converted them to L[![enter image description here][1]][1] they turn mix of green and yellow?

````
#pImg is from pillow library 

pImg.open("img0152.jpg").convert("L").resize(200,200))

```
````

Comment: Welcome to Data Science Stack Exchange. Could you please share the code you have used to generate the image?

Comment: @Miss.Alpha I edited my thread with the code

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to convert them from
**RGB to BGR** or vice versa. Plus OpenCV works best for this kinda task

Comment: I'm working on CNN and I always thought it's best to use grayscale for image classification,  should I convert it to BGR then grayscale?

Comment: Converting an image to grayscale depends on the problem. But let's say this for this problem you want to convert it to grayscale. Just use your above code to convert it to grayscale for the network it will be ok. But when you want to view the image let's say you are using matplotlib this is wat I'm familiar with. **plt.imshow(image, cmap="Greys") ** but it will have this silvish color.. But converting it to BGR myt be the best way only if you want to view it not foe the network

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).